# android studio glass and android flavor compilation false positive errors

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have the following build.gradle file in android studio (I'm running archlinux):

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        packageName 'com.derp.lerp'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            debuggable false
            zipAlign true
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            runProguard false
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        vanilla {
            packageName 'com.android.derp.lerp'
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 19
            android.compileSdkVersion = 19
        }
        glass {
            packageName 'com.glass.derp.lerp'
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 15
            android.compileSdkVersion = 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek:15'
        }
    }
}
```

./gradlew assembleVanillaDebug will work (i.e., compile with no errors); similarly installing on a device works as well.

However, a java class in src/vanilla/java/Derp.java which contains imports for KitKatish things, e.g.:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        Log.v(TAG,"fullscreening it up");
        View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.view_fullscreen);
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        );
    }
```

are red (i.e., Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT is red, and a Ctrl-F2 claims it is an unknown symbol; similarly, any pre 15 api imports are also unknown.  But these are false positives, since we *can* compile and *can* run on a KitKat device.

So, it *looks* like android studio's syntax highlighting and error reporting for android.compileSdkVersion is defaulting to 15, but the actual compilation during assemble and install is using 19 (and hence can compile and install correctly).

Moreover, in the productFlavor section I previously had just `compileSdkVersion <whatever>` (i.e., not `android.compileSdkVersion = <whatever>`), which worked for the glass flavor, but yielded red highlighting *and* assembleVanillaDebug errored out with java compiler errors agreeing with the IDE problems.

So

1. Is `android.compileSdkVersion = <whatever>` the correct way (i.e., correct gradle syntax) to switch on different compilation SDKs (which is necessary when we want to compile to glass, using the GDK, *AND* to android, using the regular SDK)?
2. If (1) is affirmative, then is the android studio error reporting (the red highlighting, unknown symbol reports, etc.) in the source code a bug?

Comment: This is a year old question with no answer, and I'm suffering the same problem. Not just that, it seems that the IDE sometimes chokes on productFlavors with different sourcesets as well, labeling them as unknown when they are known, and labeling them as known when they are unknown.. It's really annoying and I haven't been able to find any solution as of yet.